# Hide the footer onload and show on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want as my footer to show on scroll down and hide when scroll up and reach delta. Now it is showing from beginning on scroll down is there and when scroll up is hide before reach the delta. Can anyone help me to hide it onload and show when is more than delta and hide on scroll up when is before delta?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/764396ho/

jQuery

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
       $('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    } else {
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('footer').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: can't see nav down in css in jsFiddle

Comment: `<footer class="nav-down">` if for you is making any change you can change footer form css with nav-down

Comment: By delta you mean amount of scroll since scrolling started or what?

Comment: @FlapJack well, your css `nav-down` is suppose to hide your element, because this one is applied on page load... but it is not hidding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
$('footer').hide(true);

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
  $('footer').show(true);
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
    $('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
  } else {
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('footer').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
footer {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-up {
  bottom: -40px;
}
main {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
) repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="nav-down">
</footer>
<main>
</main>
```

Above is your updated snipplet

use this to show the hide the footer

```
$('footer').hide(true);
```

Comment: One thing. The nav is hidden before reach a the delta. How can I do this?

Comment: I am talking about that nav. Is getting hidden when scroll everywhere, even on middle of page.

Comment: I want to hide it during scroll but when it reach like 200 px to top

Comment: if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
        $("#footer").hide();
    }

Comment: have you tested? Because for me is doesn't seem to make any changes

Comment: Done. I had to remove `lastTopScroll = st`